# Python gmplot 'centerLat' is not defined

Tags: python, google-maps, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to plot a simple map from google maps in Python. I use gmplot and follow the example on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmplot/1.0.5

The following code is on

Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)
and

Ipython version 4.0.1

```
import gmplot
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.428, -122.145, 16)
```

And I get the following error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d299e195e0e8> in <module>()
      1 import gmplot
      2 
----> 3 gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.428, -122.145, 16)

/home/sebastia/Documents/gmplot-1.0.5/gmplot/gmplot.pyc in __init__(self, center_lat, center_lng, zoom)
     17 
     18     def __init__(self, center_lat, center_lng, zoom):
---> 19         self.center = (float(centerLat), float(centerLng))
     20         self.zoom = int(zoom)
     21         self.grids = None

NameError: global name 'centerLat' is not defined
```

I understand the variable center_lat is initialized instead of centerLat and that is what causes the problem. Am I right? If so, how can I solve this? What is the best module to plot maps from google in python?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug (wrong variables name, look line 18):

- `centerLat` should be `center_lat`
- `centerLng` should be `center_lng`

*Reference:* https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot/commit/744ab878a17d31dc95bec3e31e9fac54fb6f216b

*Solution:*
Update to version **gmplot-1.1.0**

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. However I have a mix of versions. In Ipython I can run gmplot-1.1.0 but on Jupyter I have the older version. I'll google a bit. Thanks again!